# Looking for a tiny GPS device (including battery) that transmits its current position via SMS at a pre-selected rate

Tags: gps

Is anyone aware of a tiny packaged GPS device (including battery, suitable for attachment to a pet collar) that can upload its current location via SMS at a predetermined rate? Ideally, the upload rate, phone number and enablement status should be programmable via bluetooth. Note that it should be able to SMS beyond bluetooth range, which should be only necessary for programming.

Comment: Have you searched "GPS pet collar" to determine if any off-the-shelf units meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for the 'just right Google search term', which is half the battle, Fred.  The only stuff that popped up with my searches were devices from Amazon and Ebay who source their goods from the Far East.  And there you find language like "Provides non-disturb function, can set a certain period of time mute, prevents the work and other important time to be disturbed. Control the shooting function of mobile phone through anti-loss device and take selfies by remote control.", ill-translated descriptions that hide the fact that SMS only works within bluetooth range, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: I find that Walmart's 'chinese' can be just as bad.  It can be very difficult to determine exactly what the device can actually DO and what its limitations are from the chenglish.  So, the next challenge is trying to find an actual manufacturer with actual engineering data for the device in question, engineers being less ambiguous than salesmen.  Would anyone happen to know where to find any of THAT info for a typical 'GPS pet collar' with SMS and bluetooth capability?

Comment: Thus, still no actual answer to my actual question.

Comment: I did a different search, using "arduino sms gps tracker" and found a few prospects, but tiny doesn't apply for an instant. https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/muchika/vehicle-tracking-system-based-on-gps-and-gsm-57b814 is a DIY project using five different boards, not including a battery. There's a link in the link referring to a UK product for off-the-shelf trackers, but I was not able to determine suitability for your objective.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, there appear to be a few such collars.  Heres one

[Smart Dog Collar](https://petcare.invoxia.com/)

> **Packed with innovation**
> LTE-M connectivity: the most innovative and power-efficient network for connected devices.
> Smart geolocation using Bluetooth, Wifi Positioning System and GPS for optimal coverage and precision.
> AI-based adjustments: the algorithms adapt to your dog for increased precision and personalized insights.
>
> Smart Dog Collar has a built-in SIM card.

It does a lot more than position tracking, such as health tracking, virtual fences etc.

Note, I am not associated with it.